# $.mobile.changePage instead of $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm new in `jquerymobile`, so, how can i migrate from a simple `$.ajax()` call to a `$.mobile.changePage` ?

my normal ajax its something like this (from a `click` event):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mobile/' + content,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $(".content").html(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHTTPRequest) {
    }
});
```

basicly, all the ajax call (some simple html) will be droped inside the `$(".content");`

so, how can i do this, using `changePage`?

i try this, but he only fade the page and nothing happen, i think my target is missing, dont know.

```
$(".bottom-but-list li").on("click", function () {
    var content = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]; // get the content to url

    $.mobile.changePage("mobile/" + content, {
        transition: "flip",
        reverse: true,
        changeHash: false,
        pageContainer: $("#page")
    });
});
```

**html:**

```
<div id="main-content" class="content">
     <!-- ajax should load here -->
 </div>
```

what i'm missing ?

Comment: Have you try to use $.mobile.loadPage() instead?

Comment: try it now, but nothing happen.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage should work - it calls $.mobile.loadPage() under the hood. I'm just wondering if you are getting any JS errors in the console? The syntax looks correct. I'm a little sus why you need to specify the pageContainer. jQuery Mobile uses the body as the container by default, and that's usually what you want to go with.

Comment: pageContainer i put because i was trying to load the ajax result inside this element. Imagine that i have `home.php` , inside this page, i have a basestructure with menus and others stuffs, and there are the `div` `.content`  where the `changePage` method should drop the result inside of it.

Comment: and i dont have any erros in console, remember that the other page that i'm trying to load inside of `.content` have only simple html, no `<script/>` and anything else.

Comment: debuging now, i take it off the pageContainer and i receive a msg as `undefined` after transition effect.